# How can I step into an observable collection in C#?

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Suppose I have a subject and call OnNext(). I'd like to be able to hit F11 and then go to the callbacks that were setup on calls to Subscribe. Right now that doesn't seem possible, even when the callback is happening on the same thread.

Is there a reason that this doesn't work(I'm sure there is, I just don't know what it is).

Comment: Do you have microsoft debugging symbols enabled?

Comment: Does it work if you put a breakpoint in the callback function?